# SVN returning Access Forbidden when upgrading to 1.8+ clients

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

SVN is returning Access Forbidden when upgrading to 1.8+ clients

Our server is running:

Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) SVN/1.7.8 mod_auth_sspi/1.0.4 DAV/2

and when I try to upgrade to any of the following clients they all give Access Forbidden:

```
AnkhSVN 2.5 
TortoiseSVN 1.8.1 through 1.8.3 (1.8.0.24401 works) 
Silk SVN 1.8.1 through 1.8.3-1 (1.8.0 works)
```

**Update**: AnkhSVN 2.4 no longer works now that I've updated my local repositories to 1.8

Comment: Does the behavior in the second paragraph here describe your problem? http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#authz-fspath-syntax

Comment: The authz file checks out ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that newer versions of SVN started to capitalize the domain name. And our authz file containes all lower-case domain\username entries.